# How to have function return result type be dependent on input parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBRAdgYygEwEssBzBAXgQHIAjAVwDMGQYqEAfamgGyhrc60AhgGcQANgAsVYKEixE+EAyF1uiUclwIGdXHEJQsCALb4ATPig4wAHgwJwcEFnwjMuAsRIA+ABTACEhOAFwIInAw3gA0gY6eRKRhGLEAlGEACjBQJoRitnEOTi5uXLz8CAD8CABC5QjJjmDOru60jMysVQhYdCY0LA3hkd7APggA3nEiAO6EcDgAFgh+LniJJKmTcUE4oujtTCxUYTAgcHQwxgCMAAwIAPQPNR0sAHQM2SZ+zs2pOwg9mIynwTggzhcrj0QDNauU-ABtX5wAC6-yCu32XH2UjBQjgfB+TnRCAAvsBycAzJZrGA-FQGFAoFRoiD+Kk3nBFi4-FA6HAIPyKOMpkE+QL+W96EcYBTUkA) so far:

```
export type Encoding = 'buffer' | 'blob' | 'base64'

export default async function md2docx<E extends Encoding>(
  text: string,
  encoding: E,
): Promise<
  E extends 'blob' ? Blob : E extends 'buffer' ? number : string
> {
  switch (encoding) {
    case 'buffer': return 10 //Buffer.from(text)
    case 'blob': return new Blob([text])
    case 'base64': atob(text)
  }
}

md2docx('foo', 'blob').then(output => {
  output.arrayBuffer
})
```

I basically want to be able to pass in the encoding type to the function `md2docx` and have it return the correct type and have it be typed properly in the `output` variable. Right now my code isn't working. If I do the following, then I have to check the `output instanceof Blob` sort of thing manually, which I'd like to avoid:

```
export type Encoding = 'buffer' | 'blob' | 'base64'

export default async function md2docx<E extends Encoding>(
  text: string,
  encoding: E,
) {
  switch (encoding) {
    case 'buffer': return 10 //Buffer.from(text)
    case 'blob': return new Blob([text])
    case 'base64': atob(text)
  }
}

md2docx('foo', 'blob').then(output => {
  if (output instanceof Blob) {
    output.arrayBuffer; // .arrayBuffer property exists.
  }
})
```

Comment: I found [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgYwPYBMCWcDmAlCBnAVwBtgoBeKAbwCgooAjIpegLigCEn6BuWhggGYCIAJzZwCAW3qjedegEM8EAGwAWNnmAiMmXgF9qEAB5gkI0qEixEqXeSgBrCCCQCbydFlyES1I6bmpCgQAgrEpEogiFACBIjAaEhwUJIoAEwoSAjGADwwUCbAEHAoeB52WAB8ABR8xcbAmtq6ADR8JZ66bDDtAJRsAAoiSJJoyvm2Xjj4EQDaMAC6VVR8eADuaMAIABZQNZ2VmH2rdHQIStAA5PSCwiJXbCIQwAQiKQCMAAxQAPS-7DuogAdAIRpIag1gH0+OdLlAblxHlBnq93lA4BB1hwuDU5lDFjCzlALsoEYplOpkai3ikFMBmJCikSoIZDNQ0plssYalcBEgkFdWuSkX1gcAdiUakgCMAwLLyCsaHQZXLZcDbkJRNR9H0gA) to work better in general, but still requires assertions in the implementation

Comment: "*Right now my code isn't working.*" - please put the error message in your question. Also, blobs don't have a `.buffer`, did you mean a typed array?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I meant `arrayBuffer`. Also your example still has error mine had.

Comment: Well which error? There are multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work...

```js
export type Encoding = 'buffer' | 'blob' | 'base64'

async function md2docx(
  text: string,
  encoding: 'blob'
): Promise<Blob>;
async function md2docx(
  text: string,
  encoding: 'buffer'
): Promise<number>;
async function md2docx(
  text: string,
  encoding: 'base64'
): Promise<string>;
async function md2docx(
  text: string,
  encoding: Encoding
) {
  const x: number = 10;
  switch (encoding) {
    case 'buffer': return x; //Buffer.from(text)
    case 'blob': return new Blob([text])
    case 'base64': return atob(text)
  }
}

export default md2docx;

md2docx('foo', 'blob').then(output => {
  output.arrayBuffer
})
```

I changed `.buffer` to `.arrayBuffer`.
Also, for some reason, the TypeScript Playground didn't seem to see `return 10` as returning a number, so I made a constant number variable and returned that instead.

See [TypeScript documentation on Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)